# ASP.NET one-to-one chat application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have developed a simple ASP.NET Ajax chat appliaction.I want to upgrade it.In my project I have an online user list and I am clicking one of them to open a new web browser window (I am doing this with javascript  window.open() ). Now I want to improve my project.

I want to open a dynamic div instead of a new window.  This can be a jquery chat box as well.  So my question is:

How i will open that div or jquery box and how I will import my asp.net controls (update panel, timer etc.) into to that dynamic div ??

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [dynamic loader plugin](http://samuelmueller.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/DynamicLoader.zip) (You'll find full sample there)
First use ajax to call the user control:

```
$(function() {
        var content = $('#content');
        var btnAddCell = $('#btn-add-table');
        var tableid = 1
        //dynamically add a new table to the page when the add button is clicked
        btnAddCell.click(function() {
            $.dynamicLoader.loadUC({
                ucName: 'UserControls/TableWidget.ascx',
                queryString: 'tableid=' + tableid++,
                eventBindings: {
                    ready: function(wrappedData) {
                        content.append(wrappedData);
                    } //here is where we get the rendered html and attach to the row
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Define a service (svc) that serves the control so your jquery can make calls to them:

```
    namespace DynamicLoader
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Ajax
    {
        // Add [WebGet] attribute to use HTTP GET
        [WebGet]
        [OperationContract]
        public Stream RenderUC(string path)
        {
            Page pageHolder = new Page();
            UserControl viewControl = (UserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl(path);
            pageHolder.Controls.Add(viewControl);
            StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, true);

            //trick to output exactly what you want (without wcf wrapping it)
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output.ToString()));
        }

        // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to create is to create a dnymic tabular structure when you click on the link of the online user .
This can be done using javascript and jquery ..and on window.load()

you can refer the below link 
it shows the chat window like facebook and gmail

http://20fingers2brains.blogspot.com/2013/03/gmail-facebook-style-online-chat.html